# jquery not defind inside IIFE in webpack

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, webpack

i am using laravel mix for js bundling. but value of $ not defind inside a IIFE function in js. Here is my code

```
import $ from 'jquery';
window.$ =  $;

(function($, window) {
console.log($);
})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you missed to pass the parameter to your IIFE.

```
(function($) {
  console.log($);
})($);
```

Edit: 
In your case, just doing this makes more sense, because you are not trying aliasing variables:

```
(function() {
  console.log($);
})();
```

If you had the variable `jQuery` and you wanted to use the name `$` inside the IIFE instead of `jQuery`, then you would do:

```
(function($) {
  console.log($);
})(jQuery);
```